# Wordpress next or previous post link

Tags: php, wordpress

I a wordpress template file I want to show the next post link and if next post is not available then I want to show the previous post link.

I used the following code but it shows error message.

```
<?php if (next_post_link()) ? next_post_link('%link'); : previous_post_link('%link') ; ?>
```

I think it is php syntax error.

Any Help?

Comment: change "`if`" for `echo` and remove the very first `;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    echo (next_post_link()) ? next_post_link('%link') : previous_post_link('%link');
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry ; It gives both previous link and next link. http://alltimeplay.com/tanki-online/

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do. "If the next post is unavailable"... Do you mean if the current post is the last available post?

Comment: Next post is supposed to display Next Post link. If there is no Next post available for the latest post then it should display previous post link

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be what you were after. You will need to look at doing a conditional statement to check if the current page is the latest and (if it is) don't do the above code... That's a hint. Repeat the same process for the "previous" page but check if the previous is the very first post instead. There are a number of pagination tutorials online for WordPress.